# How to find files opened by a service/user (lsof is showing very inconsistent result)

Tags: linux, lsof

I am having an issue which may be the result of a service having too many open files.  I am trying to examine what files it has open and monitor how it changes over time.  This is on CentOS 7 so I assumed `lsof` was my friend - however, I can't make any sense of the results.

My service runs under the imaginatively titled "service_user".  It is the only process on that machine which does.

I assumed that using `lsof -u service_user` would give me files opened by that user and I could just count them (initially, then maybe examine the details).  The number here is reasonable for the service and certainly no indicaiton of a problem.  However, if I take a full `lsof` and filter myself down to those which mention service_user I get three orders of magnitude more files!

```
[root ~]# lsof -u service_user | wc -l
1442
[root ~]# lsof | grep service_user | wc -l
1631673
```

I wanted to maybe look at totals per process and user for the machine (to confirm if my process is even the culprit) and tried some simple manipulation of the `lsof` output but the columns shown differ if the `-u` flag is used or not - the full `lsof` includes a `time` column which is often blank and makes it tricky to extract columns.

I tried using the -F flag to specify columns and wrote the following script into which I piped the output of `lsof  -F pcLf`  in order to try and process it into something I could then deal with.  These results are broadly consistent with the `lsof | grep service_user` numbers - three orders of magnitude larger than the `lsof -u service_user` results

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=""
echo -e "PID\tCommand\tUser\tNumber of Files"
OUTPUT=
N=0


function add_tab() {
        OUTPUT+=$(echo -e "\t")
}

function write_out_and_reset() {
        if [[ -n "$OUTPUT" ]]; then
                echo "$OUTPUT$N"
        fi
        OUTPUT=
        N=0
}

function add_value_to_output() {
        local LINE="$1"
        OUTPUT+="${LINE:1}"
        add_tab
}

while read -r LINE || [ -n "$LINE" ]; do
        case "${LINE:0:1}" in
                'p')
                        write_out_and_reset
                        add_value_to_output "$LINE"
                        ;;
                'c')
                        add_value_to_output "$LINE"
                        ;;
                'u')
                        add_value_to_output "$LINE"
                        ;;
                'L')
                        add_value_to_output "$LINE"
                        ;;
                'f')
                        N=$((N+1))
                        ;;
                *)
                        echo
                        echo "Unknown line $LINE"
                        ;;
        esac
done

write_out_and_reset
```

### Questions

1. How can I reliably find out how many files a given process or user has open?
2. How can I reliably get a sum per user/process of how many files they have open for all open files on the machine?
3. How can I reliably list all the files open by a given user or process?

I'd like to also understand why I'm getting different results as described above, but the main question is which to trust so I can move forward with investigating my actual issue.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Copy&paste the command and output *as text*, formatted as a code block. Please [edit] your question and show a few lines of output you get with `lsof -u service_user` and a few lines of output from `lsof | grep service_user` that are *not* part of the first output.

Comment: Please describe the issue itself, not a symptom that you think is the cause of the issue.

Comment: @mashuptwice: The issue here is that I can't get a reliable count of files opened by the user

Comment: @Bodo I didn't see that as code so much as what i saw but have now replaced it with text output

Comment: @Adam It doesn't matter if it is code or output. The main point is that you should not post an image of text. The answer to the meta question refers to "... code (or error/exception messages, log files, configuration files, project files, *or anything else that is represented in textual form*) ...". You asked about the difference between `lsof -u service_user` and `lsof | grep service_user` but still don't show an example of the different output on your system.

Comment: @Bodo: I do now show the output.  As text.  `lsof -u service_user | wc -l` returns 1442 and  `lsof | grep service_user | wc -l` returns 1631673  My questions was why one was returning 1000 times more rows and I think @user1686 has answered that (it duplicates per thread that uses the file handle in the latter case).  The questions I pose are about how many files the user has open and how to see that.  What more example do you want?

Comment: Please re-read the last sentence of my first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open-file limit is per process, so I don't think it makes sense to count the open files per-user – either the specific daemon process is hitting its limit or it's not.

To see the open files of a specific process, use one of:

- `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd`
- `lsof -p <pid> -d fd -a -n`
- `lsfd -p <pid> -Q "FD >= 0"`

  (lsfd doesn't exist on CentOS 7, but can be found in newer distributions)

To list them per-user, use:

- `lsof -u <user> -d fd -a -n`
- `lsfd -Q "(USER == '<user>') && (FD >= 0)"`

Note though that both lsof and lsfd also show various other resources such as memory mappings, which *do not* count against the open-file limit. You only want to count file descriptors.

> However, if I take a full lsof and filter myself down to those which mention service_user I get three orders of magnitude more files!

Without the `-u` filter, lsof also reports every *thread* of every process – which results in duplicate output, as all threads within a process share the same file descriptors and most other resources (except in weird cases). So if a process has 10 threads (including the main thread), `lsof` will report the same file descriptor 10 times. Add the `-Ki` option to avoid that.

Comment: Many thanks.  yeah, i know the limit is per process - I was starting by thinking I could look at the user for the service to sanity-check and then that wasn't as easy as I thought:)

Comment: What is `lsof -u <user> -d fd -a -n` meant to do?  If I run `lsof -u service_user -d fd -a -n` I get no output at all...

Comment: Also `lsof -p <pid> -d fd -a -n` doesn't return any output (for a pid which shows in a simple `lsof`

Comment: It's meant to return file descriptors, but not memory mappings, cwd, exe, or other unrelated items. Does `-d fd` mean something different in the lsof version that CentOS 7 has?

Comment: Honestly, i can't make sense of what it does.  However, I think it might be sockets rather than files that are being eaten, so I might anyway run without it.  main thing was the difference with/without `-u` which you explained.  Thanks.